# How to count the records in a RadGrid? (Client-side, AJAX)

Tags: javascript, ajax, telerik, radgrid

I have a grid declaratively bound to a SQL data source. I then filter this grid and filtered results are displayed. I also have a label which displays a message like "17 records with current filters.".

What RadGrid event would I handle to update my label to display this message with an up-to-date count of the number of records displayed in the RadGrid?a

My grid uses Ajax to update the records based on filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi,

```
        bool check = false; 
        protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            if (check) 
            { 
                RadGrid1.AllowPaging = false; 
                RadGrid1.Rebind(); 
                Response.Write(RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items.Count); 
                RadGrid1.AllowPaging = true; 
                RadGrid1.Rebind(); 
            } 
        } 
        protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e) 
        { 
            if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.FilterCommandName) 
            { 
                check = true; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                check = false; 
            } 
        }
```

Thanks,
Saritha.